SQLite create properly nested JSON of related tables
I need to create a nested JSON out of a SQLite database. The problem is that the query returns duplicate records in the arrays because of the GROUP BY columns.
My parent table monitor is connected to three child-tables water, activity and meal. I created the view vData of all tables and use this as a FROM source in my query.
I do not know how to correctly apply GROUP BY. Do I need to do it with sub-queries? How to do this? Or do I need to create separate queries for each table and then merge them. How would I do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.
I want to get this json:
{
   "id":0,
   "currentDate":"2024-05-16",
   "water":[
      {
         "water_id":1,
         "amount": 2000
      }
   ],
   "activities":[
      {
         "activity_id":1,
         "activity":"walk",
         "duration": 60
      },
      {
         "activity_id":2,
         "activity":"swim",
         "duration": 30
      }
   ],
   "meals":[
      {
         "meal_id":1,
         "meal":"breakfast"
      },
      {
         "meal_id":2,
         "meal":"lunch"
      },
      {
         "meal_id":3,
         "meal":"dinner"
      }
   ]
}

This is the query that I created:
SELECT json_object(
    'id', A2.monitor_id,
    'currentDate', A2.currentDate,
    'water', json_group_array(json(A2.waterArray)),
    'movement', json_group_array(json(A2.activityArray)),
    'mealTracker', json_group_array(json(A2.mealArray))
)  
FROM (
    SELECT 
        A1.monitor_id, 
        A1.currentDate, 
        A1.water_id, 
        json_object(
        'water_id', A1.water_id,
        'amount', A1.amount
        ) AS waterArray,
        A1.activity,
        A1.duration, 
        json_object(
        'activity_id', A1.activity_id,
        'activity', A1.activity, 
        'duration', A1.duration
        ) AS activityArray,
        json_object(
        'meal_id', A1.meal_id,
        'meal', A1.meal
        ) AS mealArray
    FROM (
        SELECT 
                monitor_id, 
            currentDate,
            water_id, 
            amount,
            activity_id,
            activity,
            duration,
            meal_id,
            meal
        FROM vData
        WHERE monitor_id = 0
        GROUP BY monitor_id, water_id, activity_id, meal_id
    ) AS A1
    GROUP BY A1.water_id, A1.activity_id, A1.meal_id
) AS A2
GROUP BY A2.monitor_id;

Here are my tables and the view:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS monitor (
   monitor_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   currentDate TEXT NUL NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(monitor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS water (
   water_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   monitor_id INTEGER,
   amount INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY(water_id),
   FOREIGN KEY(monitor_id) REFERENCES monitor(monitor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activity (
   activity_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   monitor_id INTEGER,
   activity TEXT,
   duration INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY(activity_id),
   FOREIGN KEY(monitor_id) REFERENCES monitor(monitor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meal (
   meal_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   monitor_id INTEGER,
   meal TEXT,
   PRIMARY KEY(meal_id),
   FOREIGN KEY(monitor_id) REFERENCES monitor(monitor_id)
);

CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS vData 
AS
SELECT 
   mn.*, 
   w.*, 
   a.*, 
   m.*
FROM monitor mn
LEFT JOIN water w ON mn.monitor_id = w.monitor_id
LEFT JOIN activity w ON mn.monitor_id = a.monitor_id
LEFT JOIN meal m ON mn.monitor_id = m.monitor_id;


What I am getting instead is something like:
{
   "id":0,
   "currentDate":"2024-05-16",
   "water":[
      {
         "water_id":1,
         "amount": 2000
      },
      {
         "water_id":1,
         "amount": 2000
      },
      {
         "water_id":1,
         "amount": 2000
      },
      {
         "water_id":1,
         "amount": 2000
      }
   ],
   "activities":[
      {
         "activity_id":1,
         "activity":"walk",
         "duration": 60
      },
      {
         "activity_id":2,
         "activity":"swim",
         "duration": 30
      },
      {
         "activity_id":1,
         "activity":"walk",
         "duration": 60
      },
      {
         "activity_id":2,
         "activity":"swim",
         "duration": 30
      }
   ],
   "meals":[
      {
         "meal_id":1,
         "meal":"breakfast"
      },
      {
         "meal_id":2,
         "meal":"lunch"
      },
      {
         "meal_id":3,
         "meal":"dinner"
      },
      {
         "meal_id":1,
         "meal":"breakfast"
      },
      {
         "meal_id":2,
         "meal":"lunch"
      },
      {
         "meal_id":3,
         "meal":"dinner"
      }
   ]
}

